# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Ed25519 KeyPairGenerator not available

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, signature, cryptocurrency

I have been tried to use the EdDSA algorithm in order to generate keys using jar eddsa 0.3.0. However, I get `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Ed25519 KeyPairGenerator not available` when I try to do `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519");`

Also, I have the following exception `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Ed25519 Signature not available` when I try to generate signatures.
Are there any examples of how to make it work?

I've done the research but I am new to the encryption phase and I don't really get how I should make it work.

I known that the eddsaparam constructor is wrong. The code below:

```java
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EdDSA");//getInstance("ECDSA","BC");//EDDSA
            SecureRandom secureRandom=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

            EdDSANamedCurveSpec ed25519 = EdDSANamedCurveTable.getByName("Ed25519");

            EdDSAParameterSpec edDSAParameterSpec = new EdDSAParameterSpec(ed25519, "Ed25519");

            keyPairGenerator.initialize(edDSAParameterSpec,secureRandom);
```

Comment: I think perhaps you should post the code that generates the error, so that someone can reproduce it.

Comment: You can find a full working example of ED25519 signature with EDDSA-0-3-0.jar here: http://javacrypto.bplaced.net/d06-ec-kurve-ed25519-signatur-mit-einer-datei/ (it's in German but you will understand the code).

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid that "Ed25519" is a typo and it should be "EdDSA".

Assuming your pom file contains this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.i2p.crypto</groupId>
    <artifactId>eddsa</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And your code resembles this:

```
import net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProvider;

import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        // throws NoSuchAlgorithmException: EdDSA KeyPairGenerator not available
        //KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EdDSA");

        // add eddsa to the security providers
        Security.addProvider(new EdDSASecurityProvider());

        // throws: NoSuchAlgorithmException: Ed25519 KeyPairGenerator not available
        //KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519");

        // throws: NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: Ed25519 for provider EdDSA
        //KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("Ed25519", "EdDSA");

        // works
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EdDSA", "EdDSA");

        // also works
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EdDSA");
    }
}
```

Comment: the provider you are referring to is  `net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProvider` - hence a 3rd party provider not included in the JDK. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.i2p.crypto/eddsa

Comment: I forgot that! Thank  you very much. 
Right now I have to figure out what to put inside the EdDSAParameterSpec constructor.
EdDSAParameterSpec.EdDSAParameterSpec(Curve arg0, String arg1, ScalarOps arg2, GroupElement arg3)
Any suggestions?